# C# Create a LambdaExpression that compares two member properties (for EF Core HasQueryFilter)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to apply a query filter in the `OnModelCreating` method (Entity Framework Core)  for all entities which have a `ClientId` property (int). So far I am able to filter the entities but I struggle to invoke the HasQueryFilter for those entities.

The filter should compare the `ClientId` property of the current Entity with a property from a service called `ITenantProvider`.

This is how I do it manually:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasQueryFilter(a => a.ClientId == _tenantProvider.TenantId);
```

Unfortunately, the EF Core `HasQueryFilter` method without Generic takes a `LambdaExpression`:

```
public virtual EntityTypeBuilder HasQueryFilter([CanBeNullAttribute] LambdaExpression filter);
```

I don't know how I can translate the above call to a Lambda Expression. My current code looks like this:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(e =>
    e.GetProperties().Select(property => property.Name).Any(pName => pName.Equals("ClientId"))))
{
    var clientId = entityType.FindProperty("ClientId");
    if (clientId != null && clientId.ClrType == typeof(int))
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
        var filter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, clientId.PropertyInfo), Expression.Constant(_tenantProvider.TenantId), parameter);
        entityType.QueryFilter = filter;
    }
}
```

Which basically works for the first call but since I use `Expression.Constant` it doesn't work for the next request if the `_tenantProvider.TenantId` changes.

How can I compare the Entity `ClientId` property with `_tenantProvider.TenantId` at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to get the runtime expression equivalent of the

```
_tenantProvider.TenantId
```

is to build a compile time parameterless lambda expression and get its [Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
var left = Expression.Property(parameter, clientId.PropertyInfo);
Expression<Func<int>> tenantId = () => _tenantProvider.TenantId;
var right = tenantId.Body;
var filter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(left, right), parameter);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much Ivan , you saved my day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the instance of TenantProvider does not change:

Then instead of the constant expression you could use

```
Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(_tenantProvider),"TenantId");
```

If you reinstantiate it at some point this will not work anymore.

Suppose you have some static property that provides the tennant id, then you could use:

```
Expression.MakeMemberAccess(null,typeof(TennantIdProvider).GetMember("CurrentId")[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The _tenantProvider is registred using AddScoped so unfortunately the instance will change for each request. Also make the property static is not an option. Any other idea?